# Polymer: Uncaught TypeError: this.$$(...).fire is not a function

Tags: javascript, polymer

The selector and trigger works, just very rarely it fails and throws this error, this has occurred on chrome 55 and 56, on windows 7, 8.1, 10, and osx 10.12
Keen to understand why this could be happening and what a fallback would look like

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<dom-module id="app-pages">

  <template>

    <style>

      :host {
        display: block;
      }

      .Page {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.5s opacity;
      }

    </style>

    <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" selected-attribute="active"
                attr-for-selected="id" fallback-selection="404">
      <app-page-street class="Page" id="street" route="{{route}}" app="{{app}}"></app-page-street>
      <app-page-404 class="Page" id="404" route="{{route}}" app="{{app}}"></app-page-404>
      <app-page-photo-picker class="Page" id="photo-picker" route="{{route}}" app="{{app}}"></app-page-photo-picker>

    </iron-pages>

  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'app-pages',
      listeners: {
        'navNext': '_navNext',
        'doLookup': 'doLookup'
      },
      properties: {
        app: Object,

        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        },

        route: Object
      },
      doLookup:function () {
        this.$.edit.fire('navNextc');
      },
      _navNext: function(){
        this.$$('.Page[active]').fire('navNextc');
      }

    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```